# How can I run a perl subroutine from cli input?

Tags: perl, subroutine

I have a program I run called arsed (https://github.com/KD8EYF/TRBO-NET). In the main program there is a routine like so:

```
sub send_help($)
{
    my($id) = @_;

    $net->{'tms'}->queue_msg($id, 'ARS-E Commands: APRS, email, NOAA, Ping SMS, Who');
}
```

Is there a way I can run this from the cli and inject the missing data ($id) somehow??

ie: /usr/local/bin/arsed -e 'send_help(3162025)' kinda thing...

Thanks!!

Comment: If the subroutine was in a module it would be simple: `perl -MModule::Name -e'Module::Name::send_help(3162025)'`. Scripts are not designed to be used like this however.

Comment: Another problem with trying to use this script like a module is that the `send_help` subroutine uses a globally-scoped variable `$net` which is set up by the later code. Just compiling the script then trying to use the subroutine wouldn't work because this variable would be undefined, and it doesn't seem like you want to run the script.